# twitter app to tweet on logged in user's account

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I have created an app namely TestApp. I am expecting that when this app is launched. A user "@IamUser" logs into twitter, twitter confirms if user authorizes TestApp to tweet content on his account. Then TestApp tweets content on "@IamUser"'s account.

Could somebody please tell me how this can be achieved. Is there any documentation, tutorial or sample code for this? I assume its the most basic task.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Twitter4j's site for documentation and code samples.
You will find many other relevant examples there.

http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html